# Generic RDD in Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a scenario in which i need to save RDD's Computed into any Format. To this End, i have declared a trait as below:

trait Record extends Product with Serializable

now, in my computations, i say the RDD is of type : RDD[_ <: Record]

It works and computes fine. But when it comes to the point of saving the RDD to say in parquet Format.

```
import sQLContext.createSchemaRDD
```

The above call is a function to an implicit method which creates the schema based on the typeTag being passed in.

```
implicit def createSchemaRDD[A <: Product: TypeTag](rdd: RDD[A]) = {
    ...
}
```

Now since i have a generic RDD[_ <: Record], No TypeTag is available.

It compiles though since Record extends Product. But when it is run, pops an error "_$1 is not a class."

The Question now boils down to how to write a generic framework which can process and save RDD's of an Arbitrary Type.

Modified the Above to use The DataFrames. Still it relies on the Type Tags.

Here is the Stack Trace:

```
Exception in thread "main" scala.ScalaReflectionException: type _$1 is not a class
at scala.reflect.api.Symbols$SymbolApi$class.asClass(Symbols.scala:275)
at scala.reflect.internal.Symbols$SymbolContextApiImpl.asClass(Symbols.scala:84)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.ScalaReflection$class.schemaFor(ScalaReflection.scala:110)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.ScalaReflection$.schemaFor(ScalaReflection.scala:29)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.ScalaReflection$class.schemaFor(ScalaReflection.scala:64)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.ScalaReflection$.schemaFor(ScalaReflection.scala:29)
at org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext.createDataFrame(SQLContext.scala:367)
at org.apache.spark.sql.SQLImplicits.rddToDataFrameHolder(SQLImplicits.scala:47)
at com.weather.logmetrics.builders.ParquetBuilder$$anonfun$save$1.apply(ParquetBuilder.scala:30)
```

and here is the how the DataFrame is created.

```
def createDataFrame[A <: Product : TypeTag](rdd: RDD[A]): DataFrame = {
    ....
}
```

Any Pointers are much appreciated.

Comment: Sounds like something DataFrames are supposed to solve. Any reason not to use them?

Comment: @Reactormonk care to add details on you comment?

Comment: @manojlds why don't you use dataframes right off the bat?